# DELETING all links from RitchTextBox with a button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to write a C# code that deletes any text that contains the embedded link from the RichTextBox Text and displays the rest text in another RichTextBox after a button click. Just simple as it sounds. i tried and fialed.

The attached image may explain more accurately what I mean.. I am trying to delete the text linked by a hyperlink. Unfortunately, the text still exists even though its hyperlink has been deleted.

[image]

this is my code:

```
// Get the text from the RichTextBox.
string text = richTextBox1.Text;

// Remove all embedded links and the text that contains them from the text.
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"http[^\s]+", "");

// Display the resulted text in RichTextBox2.
richTextBox2.Text = text;
```

Comment: The `Text` property shows the text on the screen.  The `Rtf` property is the real source of the rich text.